# MacBook Pro with Dual Monitors

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt

I have a MacBook Pro 2011, i7, 8 GB RAM, Apple SSD, but I don't know if the display is Retina or not. I also got two monitors. I am using a Thunderbolt cable to connect the first Monitor. Can you please tell me what is the name of the port between the Ethernet and the Thunderbolt port and if it's possible to use it to connect the second Monitor? This is the photo of the MacBook Pro.

[image: Macbook Pro]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The port between the Ethernet port and the Thunderbolt port is a FireWire 800 port.

On the MacBook Pro 2011 17" the Thunderbolt port supports up to two Thunderbolt displays.

As to using the FireWire port to support a display I do not know for sure other then [this article](http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/connect-your-mac-two-or-more-monitors-3621421/) essentially says no.

> USB and Firewire for two or more displays?
>
> Apple famously championed the Firewire standard a few years ago but
>   you simply can’t attach a monitor via Firewire. Firewire can receive
>   video signals from the likes of digital video cameras but isn’t
>   designed to output them.

Comment: Thank you. Only the MacBook Pro 2011 17" support up to two Thunderbolt or also the 15" ?

Comment: @user3235881, The MacBook Pro 2011 15" also support up to two Thunderbolt displays.